# Show that: $\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^2e^{-x^2}}{dx} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x^2}}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, gaussian-integral

I am fully uncertain of how to approach this problem:

Show that: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^2e^{-x^2}}{dx} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x^2}}{dx}$$

We've just completed the section on improper integrals in our book, and it seems that I haven't the necessary knowledge required to give a proof for this. The **most elementary approach** to this proof (considering that the furthest I've gotten in maths is improper integrals, thus far) would be ideal. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using integration by parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach 1:

Write

$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx =\frac12 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\tag1$$

Then, take the derivative of $I$ to find

$$I'(a)=-\int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-ax^2}dx=-\frac14 \sqrt{\pi}a^{-3/2}$$

And we are done after setting $a=1$.

---

Approach 2:

Use integration by parts to show

$$\int_0^{\infty}x^2\,e^{-x^2}dx=\left. xe^{-x^2}\right|_0^{\infty}+\frac12 \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\frac12 \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$$

as expected!

Comment: How am I meant to know that expression to be true? As I've said, we've only just recently finished with improper integrals. We've never discussed the Gaussian integral or any of its properties. So we're not privy to that information. How might I prove this expression to be true without prior knowledge of the properties of this integral?

Comment: If you're concerned about Gaussian integral, then simply ignore the first approach. The second approach uses nothing more than basic computational calclulus techniques.

Comment: @alex The integration by parts approach shows the relationship without reference to the actual values of the integrals.  But it shows that the first is one-half the second.  And that does answer the question.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. I'd tried that approach, but was a bit confused when then faced with the resultant integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x^2}}{dx}$ (from the parts) which I'd sill-ily attempted to evaluate.

Comment: @Dr.MV  I believe what your second approach meant to say was misplaced. Review it, perhaps?

Comment: @Alex Ah.  Great catch! +1 for your helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

You may integrate by parts
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^2e^{-x^2}}{dx} &=\left. x\times \frac{-e^{-x^2}}{2}\right|_0^{\infty}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\:dx\\\\
&=0+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\:dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\:dx\\\\
&=\color{blue}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}}
\end{align}
$$ where we have used a well known [gaussian result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: Well known to whom? Not I. This is an expression whose integrals and integrands have never been seen by our class, much less integrated. Additionally, your argument here is confusing.

Comment: @Alex What exactly is confusing? Oliver simply integrated by parts.

Answer (score 0):

Approach 3:

Consider the integral:

$$I(\epsilon) = \int_0^{\infty}\exp\left[-(1-\epsilon)x^2\right]dx$$

If you expand this in powers of $\epsilon$ then you see that the first order term will be the desired integral. To compute that term, you can do a change of variables by putting:

$$x = \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon}}$$

This yields:

$$I(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\epsilon}}\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-t^2\right)dt$$

We then see that

$$I(\epsilon) = I(0)\left[1 + \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\epsilon^2\right) \right]$$

The integral is thus $\frac{1}{2}I(0)$, because that is the coefficient of $\epsilon$ in $I(\epsilon)$.